# How to get type of nested object keys

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have JSON data in the following format:

```json
{
  "East": {...},
  "West": {...},
  "North": {...},
  "South": {...},
  "Kigali": {...},
}
```

which corresponds to the provinces in Rwanda. Each province key also has an object containing the different districts like so.

```json
{
  "East": {
    "Nyagatare": {...},
    "Gatsibo": {...},
    "Kayonza": {...},
    "Nyagatare": {...},
    {...}
  }
}
```

and these districts containing different sectors as well. The sectors contain cells and finally the cells contain villages.

```
Rwanda -> Province -> District -> Sector -> Cell -> Village
```

Here is a portion of the data

```json
{
  "East": {
    "Bugesera": {
      "Gashora": {
        "Biryogo": [
          "Bidudu",
          "Biryogo",
          "Buhoro",
          "Gihanama",
          "Kagarama",
          "Kanyonyomba",
          "Karutete",
          "Kivugiza",
          "Rugunga"
        ],
        "Kabuye": [
          "Bidudu",
          "Kabuye",
          "Karizinge",
          "Rwagasiga",
          "Rweteto"
```

The problem is how to get Typescript types for each of the administrative structures. Also, please let me know if there would a perf hit to generate such a large number of types.

I only have figured on how to reach the District level, but I can't go further:

```
import rwanda from "~/constants/rwanda.json";

// this module will export types and functions necessary to work with countries data
// rwanda is a country data from the json file
// it has the following structure:
// Record<Province,
//   Record<District,
//     Record<Cell,
//       Record<Village
// >>>


type Rwanda = typeof rwanda;
type Province = keyof Rwanda;
type District = keyof {
  [province in Province as keyof Rwanda[province]]: "hello";
}
```

If you can help me, I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: please share minimum reproducible example. ALso, please take a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#import-assertions), you can assert json type

Comment: I would expect a generic tree type, e.g. type Tree = Record<string, Tree>

Comment: Generating types for each key in such structure seems silly. Why you do that ?

Comment: @MichalLevý it's silly. i better stop it